# How can I print out this list alphabetically in javascript?

Tags: javascript, linked-list

I would like to sort this linked-list alphabetically. This is for a homework assignment. After extensive research I have not found anything that helps so hopefully someone here can. This is my first ever post on stackoverflow so hopefully I did it correct.

Thanks in advance.

```js
console.log("*********** Section: 2 ***********");
console.log("Sorted Book List");

class Node {
  constructor(data, next = null) {
    this.data = data;
    this.next = next;
  }
}


class LinkedList {
  constructor() {
    this.head = null;
  }
printList() {
    if (!this.head) {
      return;
    }
let node = this.head;
    let str = "";
while (node) {
      str += node.data + " ";
      node = node.next;
    }
    return str;
  }
}



const a = new Node("To Kill a Mockingbird, ");
const b = new Node("Huckleberry Finn, ");
const c = new Node("Pride and Prejudice, ");
const d = new Node("Lord of the Flies, ");
const e = new Node("Alice in Wonderland, ");
const f = new Node("The Old Man and the Sea, ");
const g = new Node("Atlas Shrugged");

l = new LinkedList();
l.head = a;
a.next = b;
b.next = c;
c.next = d;
d.next = e;
e.next = f;
f.next = g;


console.log(l.printList());
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to iterate and swap data.

Look into this implementation:
https://www.javatpoint.com/program-to-sort-the-elements-of-the-singly-linked-list

Look into the sortList() part.